# Linear functions and equations in text

Tags: geometry, word-problem

The question is:

> A rectangle has a width of 28cm. The one side is 2cm longer than the
>   other side.

We are supposed to form an equation and then solve it, but I don't know to form an equation from that.

Comment: Have you tried to actually form an equation?

Comment: What side does "the one side" refer to?

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

1. What is the width of a rectangle?
2. What are the sides of a rectangle?
3. What do you want to determine?
4. What can be equated?
5. Is the solution to that problem really unique?